# Is there way merge PDF files in reportlib with python3?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I want to merge several PDF files and make single PDF file

but I couldnt find API in reportilb width python

How can I find that?

I also use ubuntu OS is there any good utility for my question?

Comment: What is "reportilb" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/), a nice command-line tool for this kind of thing.